# SelectKBest - Feature Selection - Python - SciKit Learn

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, feature-selection, scikit-learn

I am learning about the feature selection using Python and SciKit learn. I came across the SelectKBest class, however it is unclear what kind of test is performed.

```
Select features according to the k highest scores.
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest

The only reference for k-score I found was from the following wikipedia page.

```
Cohen's kappa coefficient is a statistic which measures inter-rater agreement for qualitative (categorical) items.
```

Is the k-score from SelectKBest class refers to the above? Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, `SelectKBest` works differently.

It takes as a parameter a score function, which must be applicable to a pair ($X$, $y$). The score function must return an array of scores, one for each feature $X[:, i]$ of $X$ (additionally, it can also return p-values, but these are neither needed nor required). `SelectKBest` then simply retains the first $k$ features of $X$ with the highest scores.

So, for example, if you pass `chi2` as a score function, `SelectKBest` will compute the chi2 statistic between each feature of $X$ and $y$ (assumed to be class labels). A small value will mean the feature is independent of $y$. A large value will mean the feature is non-randomly related to $y$, and so likely to provide important information. Only $k$ features will be retained.

Finally, `SelectKBest` has a default behaviour implemented, so you can write `select = SelectKBest()` and then call `select.fit_transform(X, y)` (in fact I saw people do this). In this case `SelectKBest` uses the `f_classif` score function. This interpretes the values of $y$ as class labels and computes, for each feature $X[:, i]$ of $X$, an $F$-statistic. The formula used is exactly the one given here:  [one way ANOVA F-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#Multiple-comparison_ANOVA_problems), with $K$ the number of distinct values of $y$. A large score suggests that the means of the $K$ groups are not all equal. This is not very informative, and is true only when some rather stringent conditions are met: for example, the values $X[:, i]$ must come from normally distributed populations, and the population variance of the $K$ groups must be the same. I don't see why this should hold in practice, and without this assumption the $F$-values are meaningless. So using `SelectKBest()` carelessly might throw out many features for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Got it. It is simply a scoring function that takes in a method/test as a parameter. Thanks!

Comment: hi just to confirm, for non normal data would you say chi2 is best?